# How to use WIX with Dotfuscator

Tags: wix, dotfuscator

I've been trying to import an obfuscated project (with Dotfuscator) into an existing WIX installer package, but I can't figure out where to start.  Currently the WIX project just has a reference to the application project.  But when I pipe the application project into Dotfuscator, I am unable to add a reference to the Dotfuscator project.  I'm unaware of any other way to add a project to WIX.

I have the Dotfuscator pro edition.

Answer (score 2):

Just as in other .NET project types, WiX supports project references and direct file references.  In fact, the WiX projects and the application projects could be in two different solutions.  You could build your app, obfusacate and then build your WiX solution and pick up the obfusacated assemblies.

In other words, this is more of a build issue then it is a WiX issue.

Comment: Yes, but my question is can you add a project reference to a Dotfuscator project in WIX?  It appears the answer is no to me.

Comment: Are Dotfuscator projects MSBUILD based?  That's the underlying tech.

Comment: I think they are, the xml in the file is using this namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003.  The problem is that the Dotfuscator project doesn't even appear in the add references dialog.

Comment: Can you add a reference from other project types?  I could imagine a hack where you have a fake project with reference just to get things coied over and then add that as a reference to WiX. Otherwise I'm not sure. I'd have to setup that environment and troubleshoot.

Comment: Yeah you can add a reference to regular c# projects.  I was able to modify the WIX xml to include by obfuscated binaries, but simply adding a reference would have been the preferable solution.